# MySQL RLIKE missing information

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM A, B, C, D WHERE A = 1 AND B RLIKE '^[0-9]'
```

The above command will collect data in A =1 and B starting from the number 0 to 9.  For example, it will collect 111,112,113,114, etc. However, the above command will always miss some data comparing to separating it into RLIKE '^[0]', RLIKE '^[1]',etc., as shown below.

```
SELECT * FROM A, B, C, D WHERE A = 1 AND B RLIKE '^[0]'
SELECT * FROM A, B, C, D WHERE A = 1 AND B RLIKE '^[1]'
SELECT * FROM A, B, C, D WHERE A = 1 AND B RLIKE '^[2]'
SELECT * FROM A, B, C, D WHERE A = 1 AND B RLIKE '^[3]'
SELECT * FROM A, B, C, D WHERE A = 1 AND B RLIKE '^[4]'
SELECT * FROM A, B, C, D WHERE A = 1 AND B RLIKE '^[5]'
SELECT * FROM A, B, C, D WHERE A = 1 AND B RLIKE '^[6]'
SELECT * FROM A, B, C, D WHERE A = 1 AND B RLIKE '^[7]'
SELECT * FROM A, B, C, D WHERE A = 1 AND B RLIKE '^[8]'
SELECT * FROM A, B, C, D WHERE A = 1 AND B RLIKE '^[9]'
```

In the above example,

```
SELECT * FROM A, B, C, D WHERE A = 1 AND B RLIKE '^[1]'
```

It will always collect 111,112,113,114,115,121 where "115" and "121" are the extra which "    SELECT * FROM A, B, C, D WHERE A = 1 AND B RLIKE '^[0-9]'" cannot see. Using REGEXP will have the same result. May I know if there is any comment?  Thanks.

```
We are using MySQL 5.1.39.
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this with MySQL 5.1.61 (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/d1363/1)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your comment! http://sqlfiddle.com is an amazing stuff!

Comment: hmm so it might be a MySQL version issue then?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a difference. Can you give me the exact query. The above query is malformed and difficult to place why 115 & 121 are not getting selected.